# How to predict one data point at a time then update the network using all the data including the last using an LSTM

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm

I have a Data set of 27 features, 1012 training data and 125 for testing.
Using an LSTM Network i trained the data on the training set. But when testing it i don't want it to predict all 125 at once because i'm working with time series. Instead i would like the network to iterate through the test data, predict one point at a time and update itself incrementally.
For that purpose i wrote the following code which iterates over the test data using the index:

```
Predictions = list()
for i in range(X):
        model = load_model('model %s' %i)
        y_pred = model.predict(x_test_t[i], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
        y_pred = y_pred.flatten()

        # Descaling the Predicted Values
        Dynamic_Trainer.pred = (y_pred * min_max_scaler.data_range_[3]) + min_max_scaler.data_min_[3]
        Dynamic_Trainer.test = (y_test_tt * min_max_scaler.data_range_[3]) + min_max_scaler.data_min_[3]

        #Saving the model for each new data point predicted and added to training
        u = i+1
        model = model.save(Output_path + \Model %d'%u)

        # Saving each new prediction (Dynamic_Trainer is the function i made of the LSTM)
        Predictions.append(Dynamic_Trainer.pred)
```

However i get this error: 
`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (4, 27)`

TLDR: How can i iterate over 3 dimensional data to extract one 3d data at a time and feed it to the network.

EDIT: If there's a more efficient way to achieve the same goal, i am open for suggestions.

Comment: 4 is the time_step dimension of LSTM?

Comment: Yes, time_step = 4 and batch_size = 1

Comment: ok, try in this way... y_pred = model.predict(x_test_t[i][None,:,:])

Comment: I got this error: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [125, 1]

Comment: x_test_t[i].shape I think is (4,27) ==> x_test_t[i][None,:,:].shape I think is (1,4,27). (1,4,27) is (batch, time_step, n_features) which is as the model expect

Comment: I made some adjustments and you are right. the shapes are exactly how you specified but i still get the same error: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [125, 1] (I apologize i'm still a beginner at this)

Comment: if you pass to the model (1, time_step, n_features) it may return you (1, n_output)

Comment: I seems like the error was my doing in a different part of the code. Your instruction is absolutely correct and my code works now. Thank you immensely!

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found thanks to @Marco Cerliani for anyone with the same issue is to just use: y_pred = model.predict(x_test_t[i][None,:,:]) for the loop.